# Yii2 Pagination + PrettyURL Cannot Find site/index

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have pagination setup in `site/index`, with pretty url working. But my `site/index` is hidden by either the rewrite engine of Apache, or by `UrlManager`. In any case, my index page address is simply "X.COM' and pagination wishes to redirect a page change to "X.COM/index?PAGINATIONQUERY", so it always returns a 404.

Example Pagination Request (Returns 404):

```
x.com/index?page=2&per-page=12
```

Here is my `UrlManager`

```
        'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [

            // '<alias:\w+>' => 'site/<alias>',
            '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',


        ],
    ],
```

How would I either remove the 'index' portion from pagination requests, or allow myself to see /index in Url again?
Thank you!

Edit: 
This is my Index action

```
    public function actionIndex()
{
    $query = Shout::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC]);
    $countQuery = $query->count();
    $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery, 'pageSize' => 12]);
    $shouts = $query->offset($pagination->offset)
        ->limit($pagination->limit)
        ->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
         'shouts' => $shouts,
         'pagination' => $pagination,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Are all actions directed to the siteController? Still only need to support `x.com/?page=2&per-page=12`

Comment: @Luna All actions are directed to siteController, yes. I would only need to support the piece as you stated, but to have /index back would be great. Just not sure how to do that.

Comment: I used the same UrlManager configuration to pass the test, do you have any other clues? For example, is there an index method in the siteController?

Comment: @Luna I have updated with my actionIndex in siteController

Comment: If you temporarily change the `actionIndex` to `public function actionIndex() {return "<div>hi</div>"}` Is it normal to access?

Comment: @Luna It displays the html @ `x.com`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185345/discussion-between-d-milk-and-luna).

Answer (score 0):

Use Yii2 Gii for Generating Crud Modules with Inbuilt Pagination & Searching.

Yii2 Gii - https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-gii

Make Sure Pjax enable when create crud with Gii.

Comment: Hello @Anil - It'll be helpful if you can post some code snippets.

Comment: @Kishen Follow posted URL it'll contain steps with snippets to setup gii.